# An easy number choosing problem

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> Suppose we have $k$ identical sets $A$ consisting of $n$ integers. How
>   many ways are there to choose $k$ numbers $(a_1,...,a_k)$ such that
>   $a_i\in A$? The order of numbers matter.

At first I thought the answer is $\dbinom{kn}{k}$ but this is not true. Could you help?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, here is the answer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition

Comment: Does that take into account that the order matters?

Comment: @zach yes it does

Comment: It seems like the article says that order is not taken into account.

Comment: It says that it disregards different orderings, I think I explained myself wrongly. But this is what I meant.